# Unset many session from application in php but not all

Tags: php, html, sql, session

I am working on a php web application which have many sessions variable. I want to unset some of them.

I dont want to write many lines code

```
unset($_SESSION['a']);
unset($_SESSION['b']);
unset($_SESSION['c']);
unset($_SESSION['d']);
unset($_SESSION['f']);
unset($_SESSION['a']);
```

Is to possible to *unset* this all by one method ?

Thanks

Comment: first check in google then come here.

Comment: @karsho i check man and not found thats why put here...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unset accepts more that one variable, you could just pass them all in - or create a list like so:-

```
<?php
$keys = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd');

foreach ($keys as $key) {
    unset($_SESSION[$key]);
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Method 1:

```
$removeKeys = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e');

foreach($removeKeys as $key) {
   unset($_SESSION[$key]);
}
```

Method 2:

```
unset($_SESSION['a'], $_SESSION['b'], $_SESSION['c']);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can group array elements and then do unset to whole group.

```
$_SESSION['foo']['a'] = 'value_a';
...
$_SESSION['foo']['f'] = 'value_f';

unset($_SESSION['foo']);
```